# How to query with maximum number of rows with same value?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query, greatest-n-per-group

In Mariadb 10.5.8
I have a table with some repeating value e.g.

```
Item , qty
shoes 3
pants 2
pants 2
pants 4 
shoes 3
pants 2
shoes 6
pants 2
shoes 3
pants 2
```

I want to query up to 3 occurrences of each Item. so it will return

```
Item , qty
shoes 3
pants 2
pants 2
pants 4
shoes 3
shoes 6
```

Note it stopped picking each item (shoes, pants) after picking the first 3 occurances.

Comment: I would use the row_number window function and partition by "Item".

Comment: Please provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE xyz\G;` for your table. You have, for example, 4 entries of `pants 2` in one field (AIUI) - without being able to distinguish between them, those values are, to all intents and purposes, useless - unless they're (for example) daily sales without a timestamp and you have a very primitive (manual?) POS system - and you want a `SUM()` or similar? What's the rationale behind getting the first three and not the fourth?

Comment: See the tag I added.

Comment: It would be more help if you provide an exact output you want.